# When installing software with Wine it does not put an Icon on the applications menu. Xubuntu 10.04

Tags: wine

When I install software with wine it appears to install correctly but does not add that program to the applications menu. I don't know the command to run the program from the command line so I can never run that program except through the wine installation command. How do I add that program to the menu? I am running wine from the terminal, but I believe the result is the same when starting it from the menu.
Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

This question have an easy way to solve.
Do this things

1. Create your own `.desktop` file
2. Add that `.desktop` file to there where you want

## Create your own `.desktop` file

Just create a new file and set its name `somthing.desktop`. It is important that extension is `.desktop`. In that write this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=(Apps name)
Exec=(command to execute(for example wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/(And Path)))
Icon=(select an icon and write its path here)
Type=Application
```

---

## Add that `.desktop` file to there where you want

You can try just draging method or use `Main menu` to add `New Item`
[image: main menu]

Answer (score 0):

You may also try to install PlayOnLinux and install your app from there. It's much easier and you can install as many wine versions.