# Create unity shortcuts to WINE applications 12.04

Tags: unity, 12.04, wine, shortcuts

I have just gone through the process of getting ubuntu onto my main PC, no issues, was absolutely brilliant how its done it and loved that I could read the web while installing too,

I have WINE installed and world of warcraft works fine having copied the installation over from the existing windows partition that I have in place, the only trouble I am having now is creating a meaningful shortcut for the application to launch it direct, rather than browsing the directory and double clicking launcher to start it off.

I have followed every angle possible on here and google search so far and it seems to have not worked, I want to know is this possible and should I just go with a new download and installation to my home directory rather than just copying the files over to the new /home directory and running them through there or am I missing something easy here ?

Comment: take look: http://askubuntu.com/questions/136284/when-installing-software-with-wine-it-does-not-put-an-icon-on-the-applications-m/136290#136290

Comment: You didn't explain the problem you were having while creating the icon. Did you not know how to create the icon or was the icon you were creating just not working?

Comment: I have sorted it now, thanks for replying though, I have installed playonlinux and its sorted out all the desktop shortcuts for me now for my games.

Comment: Can you add that as an answer @rich_tech

Comment: See this [link](http://diynp.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-create-launcher-icon-manually-in.html) This blog is by me.Comment if it works I will add it to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alacarte` to solve this problem:
Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

- Start `alacarte`.
- Go to wine - programs - ... (where your wine program is located).
- Move the program icon to another folder (outside of wine; e.g., office).
- Close `alacarte`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HUD - Alt+f2 - and search for the program you want. When it's icon appears in the HUD click and hold it, then drag it to an empty part of the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me; creating "Word" desktop Icon as an example....

Look for the launcher "icon" you use to start the wine program via the "Search Applications" display in Dash; that "Search Applications" view "launcher" is next to the "home" icon at the bottom of Dash screen (dash needs to be out of full-screen mode). Click and drag the icon you use to launch the Wine app to your desktop. Right click on that new desktop icon and change permissions to "Allow executing file as program".

You can change the default launcher icon from "wine" icon as well. Do a Google search for your application icon; e.g. "word icon" and download image. Change "properties" of the desktop launcher (right-click that icon), click on icon image there. Select your new downloaded icon image.

This will make more sense when you are working the GUI.