# Running a windows screensaver via wine

Tags: wine, kubuntu, kde, screensaver

I'm trying to get [Free Fire Screensaver](http://www.laconicsoftware.com/free-fire-free-screensaver.php) to run on my Kubuntu 14.10 machine. I've managed to install it under wine and now have an .exe file to start the fire effect (which works exactly as it should, go wine!). However I am at a loss as to how I can get Kubuntu to use it as a screensaver. I've tried creating a custom screensaver under '/usr/share/applications/screensavers/' by copying one of the existing files and then replacing the proper values with my .exe file but it just won't show up in the screensaver select screen. I'd be grateful if anyone could explain how I can get it to work or offer a worthy alternative. IT IS VITAL THAT MY COMPUTER HAS SOME SORT OF FIRE EFFECT.

Comment: see also http://wiki.winehq.org/ScreenSavers . you may need to create a launcher http://askubuntu.com/questions/136346/create-unity-shortcuts-to-wine-applications-12-04

Comment: I found a way to get it working!
KDEs power management settings (also Called Energy Saving) have a "Run Script" option, which can be set to run after a specific amount of time.
I used it to run the following script:  
`#! /bin/bash
#Screen is locked after $timeout seconds have passed
timeout=30
date1=$(date +"%s")
wine /path/to/Fire\ Screensaver.exe
date2=$(date +"%s")

diff=$(($date2-$date1))
if [ "$diff" -ge $timeout ]
then
    #locks the screen in the background
    qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver Lock
fi`  
Look to your screens KDE users, the web is dark and full of terrors.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be `xscreensaver`.

Install it by:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-data* xscreensaver-gl*
```

You can configure it with `xscreensaver-demo`. This opens a GUI window which allows you to chose one of a huge number of different screensavers:

[image: xscreensaver-demo window showing xflame preview]

For your love to flames, I would recommend you the saver **XFlame**. It can also take a different picture as background and set it on fire.
If you would also appreciate a nice firework, you could try **Fireworkx**.

Comment: I've installed xscreensaver and tried getting XFlame to do what I want (take screenshot of desktop and apply fire effects to it) but it won't accept any image I give to it saying the resolution is either too large or too small. The command I set for it (in xscreensaver settings) is`xflame -root -bitmap /path/to/picture`. I've tried different image files with different resolutions but it keeps giving me the resolution error. It does have superior fire effects to Free Fire Screensaver though. If only it worked properly...

Comment: @seeker_of_free_fire I have to admit I only use XMatrix and Fireworkx, so I have no experience with the XFlame screensaver. But I will look if I can find out how it works...